# "Gmail style" partial update of a web form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

We have an old web project written with technology ASP.NET Web Forms. This website has a usual registration form, where user is required to fill in a phone number.

I want to check on the run that this phone number is unique i.e. no other registered user has already used this phone number. Of course there is no need to send the whole form to the back-end, good example of this behavior could be how gmail checks if the email your are typing is free for registration.

I tried to adapt an [example from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.140).aspx) and use two standart ajax components: **ScriptManager** and **UpdatePanel**.

My crazy implementation is:

1. input-field "phonenumber" looses focus so this triggers "checkPhoneNumber"
2. javascript function "checkPhoneNumber" clicks the button "ValidatePhoneNumber"
3. Back-end writes "Valid/Invalid phone number" in a label

Probably this is extremly bad and compicated practise, but somehow it works so far.

**The problem** is that I want to make more changes on the webpage with help of javascript (add&remove some classes to visualize the error/success) in "onchange" event of the label that never runs. Is it because the change was made by server and not by user?

---

**Code** in "registration.aspx":

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function checkPhoneNumber()
        {
            alert("test"); //alert does not work!
            document.getElementById("<%=btnValidatePhoneNumber.ClientID%>").click();
        };

        function validationLabelOnChange()
        {
            //Never comes here!
            var label = document.getElementById("<%=ValidationLabel.ClientID%>");
            alert(label.text);
        };

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="padding-top: 10px">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset style="border: none">
                <asp:Label ID="ValidationLabel" runat="server" Text="" onchange="validationLabelOnChange"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnValidatePhoneNumber" runat="server" OnClick="btnValidatePhoneNumber_Click" Text="Button" />
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Code** in "registration.aspx.cs":

```
    protected void btnValidatePhoneNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Validation of phone number will be added here
        ValidationLabel.Text = "Refreshed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

I appreciate if you can propose a better solution! I guess it could work even without UpdatePanel.

Comment: validating the phone number on the back-end is definitely the way to do this when using ajax to validate the entries.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'd better use [Page Methods](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2). Update Panels are fine and all but they are better option when you need to return HTML rendered on the server. For a simple true/false type of request you'd better use something more lightweight. Page methods are basically a static method in your page class with an easy to use JavaScript proxy function generated by ASP.NET for you.